# print 5th word in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to find out the 5th word after a string of words from a SQL file.

string = INSERT INTO record

**SQL file:**

```
LOCK TABLES `zone1` WRITE;

/*!ALTER TABLE `zone1` DISABLE KEYS */;

/*!ALTER TABLE `zone1` ENABLE KEYS */;

UNLOCK TABLES;
--
-- 
--
LOCK TABLES `zone2` WRITE;

/*!ALTER TABLE `zone2` DISABLE KEYS */;

/*!ALTER TABLE `zone2` ENABLE KEYS */;

UNLOCK TABLES;

INSERT INTO record VALUES ('All', 'people', 'seems', 'to', 'need', 'data', 'processing'),('Randomly','words','picked','to','complete','the','sentence')

INSERT INTO record VALUES ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7')

INSERT INTO record VALUES ('8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14')

 LOCK TABLES `zone3` WRITE;

/*!ALTER TABLE `zone3` DISABLE KEYS */;

/*!ALTER TABLE `zone3` ENABLE KEYS */;

UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- 
--
LOCK TABLES `zone4` WRITE;

/*!ALTER TABLE `zone4` DISABLE KEYS */;

/*!ALTER TABLE `zone4` ENABLE KEYS */;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

**Code**

```
import re
import fileinput
import sqlite3

fd=open('dump.sql','r')
filesql=fd.read()
fd.close()

string='INSERT INTO record'

def words(line):
    return re.sub(r'[\(\)\';]', '', line.strip()).split()

with open('dump.sql','r') as dump:
    for line in dump:
        if string in line:
            tail=line.split(string)[1]
            for group in tail.split("),("):
                print words(tail)[3]
```

When I am running this code, I get the following output:

```
seems,seems,3,10,
```

I was expecting to get:

```
seems,picked,3,10,
```

Can somebody hint me what is wrong in my code?

Thank you in advance,
Dan

Comment: in the last line, you are retrieving the value from **tail** it should be from **group**, consider changing,    print words(tail)[3] to print words(group)[3]

Comment: Not an option since I will get "list index out of range".

Answer (score 1):

This regex works

```
import re

with open('dump.sql', 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()

matches = re.findall('\((\'[^\']*\',\s*){3}', s)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Comment: Yes, for this example works good, but this was just a small part of my SQL file. If we expand this for the whole file(which is a little bit different - this is just an easy example of how my SQL file is), I won't get anything. We should stick with the idea of 5th word after the string, otherwise, won't work.

Comment: I can only give you an answer on the parts you are asking for. If you have a lot of other hidden problems that are not described in the question you did not ask a complete question. I can’t help you then...

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the start area of the string, and then print everything behind it. 
For example:

```
stringA = "Hello World My name is Robot Tim, and who are you?"

# Find the character position to start.
n = stringA.index(stringA.split()[5]);
#print(n);

stringB = stringA[n:]
print(stringB);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

I don't know if it will work for all your sql file...

```
string = 'INSERT INTO record VALUES'

with open('dump.sql', 'r') as dump:
    for line in dump:
        if string in line:
            tail = line.split(string)[1]
            for group in tail.split("),("):
                group = group.replace("\'", "").replace("(", "").replace(")\n", "")
                print(group.split(",")[2].strip())
```

### output:

```
seems
picked
3
10
>>>
```

## Get the results in a list

In case you want to get the results in a list

```
string = 'INSERT INTO record VALUES'
l = []
with open('dump.sql', 'r') as dump:
    for line in dump:
        if string in line:
            tail = line.split(string)[1]
            for group in tail.split("),("):
                group = group.replace("\'", "").replace("(", "").replace(")\n", "")
                print(group.split(",")[2].strip())
                l.append(group.split(",")[2].strip())
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed.